# Output Window not working on Visual Studio Isolated Shell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shell, vsix

I am having problem displaying text to the Output Window in Visual Studio Isolated Shell.Everything is working fine if I run the Isolated shell on a machine that has Isolated+Integrated Shell Redistributable + Visual Studio Professional 2015 + SDK installed. On a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed, the Output Window remains blank on the Isolated shell although it does work on the Integrated Shell.

I am using the following to create a custom Output Window:

```
IVsOutputWindow opWindow = Package.GetGlobalService( typeof( SVsOutputWindow ) ) as IVsOutputWindow;
Guid customGuid = new Guid("0F44E2D1-F5FA-4d2d-AB30-22BE8ECD9789");
string customTitle = "My Title";
opWindow.CreatePane( ref customGuid, customTitle, 1, 1 );
IVsOutputWindowPane opPane;
opWindow.GetPane( ref customGuid, out opPane); 
opPane.OutputString( "Hello, This is a test!" );
opPane.Activate();
```

Can someone shed some light?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. In the end it was due to DLLs version different that caused the behaviour differences.

More details can be found in this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/528e150d-99f6-4e14-801f-ff7a73d95235/#528e150d-99f6-4e14-801f-ff7a73d95235

Hope the above helps someone.